# The file doesn't exist laravel

Tags: laravel

```
public function readPDF($file_id)
{
    $file_id = SiteHelpers::encrypt_decrypt($file_id, 'd');
    $file_details = $this->model->getFileDetails($file_id);
    if($file_details){
        $file = Storage::url('app/public/course/'.$file_details->course_id.'/'.$file_details->file_name.'.'.$file_details->file_extension);
        print_r($file);
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=document.pdf');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        // @readfile($file);
        return response()->file($file);
                    }
}
```

I have this function to display uploaded pdf file. I removed the former @readfile($file); as it does nothing and displays nothing. I did troubleshoot on my file path ($file) and the resulted url displayed pdf. But when I used latter function **return response()->file($file);** it displayed error that file doesn't exist but my $file string is correct. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: make sure you understand the difference between a `path` and a `url`.  The response is wanting a path to the file (ie, where in the local filesystem is the file located)

Comment: Is there any alternative function for displaying a url then

Comment: Try this, `$file = app_path('public/course/'.$file_details->course_id.'/'.$file_details->file_name.'.'.$file_details->file_extension);`

Comment: Sure `$file = Storage::path('app/public/course/'.$file_details->course_id.'/'.$file_details->file_name.'.'.$file_details->file_extension);`